# Angular2 form submit stops working after route change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Given my form:

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveNew(f)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Text Hu</strong></label>
            <quill-editor name="textHU" [ngModel]="textHU">
            </quill-editor>

            <label class="mt-4"><strong>Text En</strong></label>
            <quill-editor name="textEN" [ngModel]="textEN">
            </quill-editor>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Component:

```
  saveNew(form: NgForm) {
        this.termsOfServiceNew.text.textEN = form.value.textEN;
        this.termsOfServiceNew.text.textHU = form.value.textHU;
        this.http.post("/api/terms_of_service/admin", this.termsOfServiceNew, this.jsonRequestOptions).subscribe(r => {
            this.termsOfServiceNew.text.textEN = "";
            this.termsOfServiceNew.text.textHU = "";
            this.toggleNewContainer();
            this.refreshList();
        });
    }
```

Every form have this attribute: `#f="ngForm"`

Should this `#f` be unique for every form?

Angular base app was generated by JHipster (springboot back-end).

I have several similar forms in my app, in different components on different routes. When I load or reload my app (ctrl+f5) and submits the form it works perfectly. It calls my API, saves data into DB. I can repeat it, it works fine, but when i navigate elsewhere (different route) then all my forms across the application stops working. When I hit the submit button, does not happen anything.
No error on console, ngSubmit methods are not called anymore.

Do you have any idea, what could cause this strange issue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without seeing more or a plunker that illustrates your issue, I'm not sure we'll be able to help much beyond guessing a few things. Are you using multiple modules? Lazy loading? AOT? Third-party products?

Comment: Yes, I have lot of modules, my app is based on JHipster generated code with spring boot backend. It's a bit difficult to demonstrate on plunker, because the basic scenario works fine, the magic happens after the navigation.

Comment: No AOT, No lazy loading.

Comment: Simple (click) works fine multiple times without forms, something is wrong about the handling of forms.

Comment: I've found the source of the issue. The problem was not with the form. After the routechange, a fileuploader component has stopped working, but tha field was required for the form, so the form was invalid, and couldn't be saved.